# How to clear all backstacks in specific fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I have an activity that contains bottom navigation bar. Every transaction to the bottom navigation holds a fragment. Inside those fragment there are several nested fragments. 
Like - MainActivity > HomeBottomNavigationFragment > AnotherFragment > AnotherFragment. 
Now when I will come again to the HomeBottomNavigationFragment I want all the backtacks to be cleared. How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```